# How to correctly nest data and write to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some Edittext that allows the user to enter data:

```
AppName
Date
Title
Quantity
User
```

I started a new Firebase project and it is currently a blank slate.

I am setting up my Firebase instance like this:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myapp.firebase.io");
```

How I want it is everytime a new adding occurs, I would like to add it like this (AppName is the common ground for all entry):

```
AppName
    Date
    Title
    Quantity
    User

    Date
    Title
    Quantity
    User
    ...
    ...

AppName
    Date
    Title
    Quantity
    User

    Date
    Title
    Quantity
    User
    ...
    ...
```

How can I do the following:

> The first time it is added, the AppName will be the parent node, and
>   anytime after Firebase should check to see if the parent node exist
>   and is the same and add it to that, otherwise create a new parent node
>   and add the children node to the new parent node.

I currently have my auth set up like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I had to change to `true` for my app to write to Firebase.

How can I:

> Not register the user but only allow the app to able to write to
>   Firebase.

EDIT:

I am doing the following:

```
mDatabase.child("AppName").setValue(etName.getText().toString()); 
mDatabase.child("AppName").child("Date").setValue(etDate.getText().toString()); 
mDatabase.child("AppName").child("Title").setValue(etQuantity.getText().toString());  
mDatabase.child("AppName").child("Quantity").setValue(User.getText().toString());  
mDatabase.child("AppName").child("User").setValue(etUser.getText().toString());
```

Instead of adding, it is overwriting the previous entry. How can I append.

Comment: So changing the rules to `true` it worked. However, how can I format the data like shown above?

Comment: when add data, firebase will automatically check whether the parent node exist. if not it will create new node.

Comment: So I got it to work but it is just overwriting the previous entry and not appending...

Comment: use push method to append data. setValue use to update data in current node

Comment: So... How can I check to see of the parent node with the 'AppName' exist before either adding new parent node or just adding to existing parent node?

Comment: You can get the key of the node using datasnapshot.getKey() method. Which is your appName.

Comment: Ok thank you. Let me try out and get back to you guys. So use getkey() if exist then push otherwise setvalue? I think i got the logic.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you, you need that not registered users could edit your database on Firebase and how to know If you added an ID.

First of all, as **Ishan Fernando said**, If you add data with the same id, this data will be overwrited, and using the push method, Firebase will create an unic ID to add you data

Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=en

This Gist, thanks to the user **realgt**, could help you to know if the Appname exists or not: https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949#gistcomment-998628
This will get all your data and you could check if you need add it or not

And, if you don't want to register users, but you need them to write the database, I think that you need to register them as anonymous users:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

Firebase needs registered users (using social networks, email o anonymously) to modify it, so **try the anonymous method**. The problem is when the user get out of your app, this user will keep registered on your database. So, I recommend you, (Please, correct me if I'm wrong) to erase the user when onStop starts and create it again when onReady starts.

I hope it helps.